# Till which version chrome supported GWT Classical Dev Mode?

Tags: gwt

What was the last Chrome version that supported GWT Classical Dev Mode? 
When did Chrome deprecate GWT plugin with classical Dev mode?

Comment: None. Update your GWT, it is fully worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

> **Release Notes for 2.6.0 (RC1)**
>   GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime
>   in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are
>   improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error
>   messages.

http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1

Chrome version 30.0 still has the classic dev mode support and firefox version 24.